# Finding an Optimal Function for $\int_b^x \frac{g(t)}{t^2} \,dt= 2 \sqrt{x} - 6$

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is the following:

Find a function $g$ and a value $b$ such that

$$\int_b^x \frac{g(t)}{t^2} \,dt= 2 \sqrt{x} - 6$$

I know that $2 \sqrt{x} - 6$ is the antiderivative of the function $\frac{g(t)}{t^2}$, but I don't know how to find that optimal function $g(t)$ that can fit the requirements in the integral. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiate both sides of

$$\int_b^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2} \,dt= 2 \sqrt{x} - 6$$

to get

$$\frac{f(x)}{x^2} = \frac1{\sqrt x}\implies f(x)=x^{3/2} $$

Then, substitute back into the integral to obtain $b=9$.

Comment: How did you know that $\frac{f(x)}{x^2} = \frac1{\sqrt x}$?

Comment: @geo_freak - use the rule $\frac d{dx }(\int^x g(t)dt )= g(x)$

Answer (score 0):

If we try for $f(t)= A t^\alpha$ for some $A$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, we get

$$
A\int_b^x t^{\alpha-2} \ \mathrm{d}t = \frac{A}{\alpha -1} \left[ x^{\alpha-1}- b^{\alpha-1}\right]
$$

since we want $\sqrt{x}$, we impose $\alpha-1 = \frac{1}{2}$, so  $\alpha = \frac{3}{2}$.
We get

$$
2A \big( \sqrt x - \sqrt{b}) = 2A\sqrt{x} - 2A\sqrt{b}
$$

so the good choice is $A=1$, $2\sqrt b = 6$, hence $b=9$.
Finally

> $$f(t)=\sqrt{x^2} \\ b = 9$$